# регулярное выражение, поиск и замена

Tags: javascript

```
url.replace(/\/?offset=\d+/g, '');
```

Данная регулярка ищет строку ?offset=любоечисло,
а мне нужно еще сделать чтобы знак ? был необязательным( то есть он может быть а может не быть).
Я пробовал так

```
url.replace(/\/?\*offset=\d+/g, '');
```

Но не сработало :(
Как правильно написать такое условие?

Comment: Данная регулярка не ищет то, что вы описываете.

Comment: Лучше опишите задачу полностью, а так же где вы её решате. Например, если это nodejs, то может быть проще использовать модуть `url`

Answer (score 1):

Еще можно вот так:

```
\??offset=\d+
```

Answer (score -1):

Вот так сработало:

```
url.replace(/\?*offset=\d+/g, '')
```

Comment: вот так сработало

Comment: Это выражение так же сработает для строки `??????offset=123`, что вряд ли является корректным поведением программы

Comment: ну и хорошо, мне не нужны знаки ?